# Show that $\|XY-YX\|^2\le2\|X\|^2\|Y\|^2$ for diagonal matrix $X$ and any matrix $Y\in M_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am studying on the topic of norm of the commutator and I would like to solve the following problems:

For any matrix $X\in M_n$, $\|X\|=\sqrt{\sum|x_{ij}|^2}=\sqrt{trA^*A}$ , where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$(So the field is $\mathbb C$).

Let $X=diag(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ be a diagonal matrix in $M_n$.
Show that $\|XY-YX\|^2\le2\|X\|^2\|Y\|^2$ for any matrix $Y\in M_n$.

This is the first part of my problem.
I try the question in this way:

$X=\operatorname{diag}(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$,
$Y=\begin{bmatrix}y_{11} & y_{12} & ... & y_{1n}\\y_{21} & y_{22} & ... & y_{2n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\y_{n1} & y_{n2} & ... & y_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$

then $$XY-YX=\begin{bmatrix}(x_1-x_1)y_{11} & (x_1-x_2)y_{12} & ... & (x_1-x_n)y_{1n}\\(x_2-x_1)y_{21} & (x_2-x_2)y_{22} & ... & (x_2-x_n)y_{2n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\(x_n-x_1)y_{n1} & (x_n-x_2)y_{n2} & ... & (x_n-x_n)y_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$

So $\|XY-YX\|^2=\sum|(x_i-x_j)y_{ij}|^2$ for $1\le i,j\le n$
and I get stuck in this step.

The second part of my problem is:

If $X$ is a normal matrix,  show that the inequality is still true.
I have no idea how to start with the second problem.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why my question is closed or how I can  modify the content so that it can be reopened? Thanks

Comment: adding some commentary on where this problem came from and what background knowledge you have would be helpful.  For example, you said *"If  is a normal matrix, show that the inequality is still true. I have no idea how to start with the second problem."*  but to most people the second part is an immediate corollary of the first since normal matrices are unitarily diagonalizable and the Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At the beginning, I keep trying to use the definition of normal matrix $AA^*=A^*A$, and thinking how I can use this definition in the calculation of norm, and that's why I don't know how to solve the problem. Once you tell me about the property that normal matrices are unitary diagonalizable, then I know that I make a silly mistake and the second problem actually is very simple. Thanks very much.

Comment: Wow! this fact (without the $X$ being diagonal assumption) was only proven in 2008 https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/preprint/2008/PREPRINT_05.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The slightly more general version of your question was in fact [Conjectured back in 2005](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82188566.pdf) for arbitrary matrices (without the assumption that $X$ is diagonal) by Bottcher and Wenzel. It was proven shortly after by [Vong and Jin](http://repository.um.edu.mo/handle/10692/15595), and you can see the follow-up paper by the authors of the conjecture [here](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/preprint/2008/PREPRINT_05.pdf) with the proof of the desired fact.

The [proof](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/preprint/2008/PREPRINT_05.pdf) by Bottcher and Wenzel doesn't appear to be simple enough to explain in an MSE post. That being said I will show you how elementary methods can get you a weaker bound that is off by a factor of only $2$.

The matrix norm you mention is called the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), so we will denote it by $\|\cdot\|_F$. To obtain a slightly weaker bound, you can use the fact that $(M_n(\mathbb{C}),\|\cdot\|_F)$ is a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) (with the Frobenius a.k.a [Hilbert-Schmidt inner-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator)), and therefore the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) holds. In other words, for any complex $n\times n$ matrices $X,Y$ we have that $$\|XY-YX\|_F^2+\|XY+YX\|_F^2=2\|XY\|_F^2+2\|YX\|_F^2.$$

Another useful fact is that the Frobenius norm is [submultiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) and therefore $$\|XY\|_F\leq \|X\|_F\|Y\|_F,$$ for any $X,Y\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Combining these two facts we can see that for *any* matrices $X$ and $Y$ $$\|XY-YX\|_F^2\leq 2\|X\|_F^2\|Y\|_F^2+2\|Y\|_F^2\|X\|_F^2=4\|X\|_F^2\|Y\|_F^2.$$

The above bound is weaker than the bound in the question (which is in fact tight), however, it can be proven using elementary results.

**Remark 1.** I have not used the fact that $X$ is diagonal... perhaps the argument in the [proof](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82188566.pdf) is easier with this assumption, however, this was not obvious...

**Remark 2** As mentioned in the comments the Frobenius norm is *unitarily invariant*, and therefore if $U\Sigma V$ is the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $X$ with $\Sigma$ being the diagonal matrix of singular values then $\|X\|_F=\|U\Sigma V\|_F=\|\Sigma\|_F$, in particular, if $X$ was normal then $V=U^*$, and the same thing would essentially hold.